# getting requested page not found error

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a link in `quiz.jsp` and if I click that link then it must go to `play.jsp` but it is giving me error requested resource not found

quiz.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
<title>play quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
Welcome ${name}
<a href="play.jsp">Play quiz</a>
</body>
</html>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  

<!-- telling container to take care of annotations stuff -->  
<context:annotation-config />  
<context:component-scan base-package="com.quiz"></context:component-scan>
<bean id="viewResolver" 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<bean id="user" class="com.quiz.model.user"></bean>
<bean id="userDaoImpl" class="com.quiz.dao.UserDaoImpl"></bean>

<!-- declare datasource bean -->  
<bean id="dataSource"  
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quiz" />  
<property name="username" value="root" />  
<property name="password" value="root" />  
</bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">  
<display-name>QUIZ</display-name>  
<welcome-file-list>  
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list>  

<servlet>  
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-
class>  
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

HomePageController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomePageController {

@Autowired
UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl;
@RequestMapping("/register")
public ModelAndView registerUser(@ModelAttribute user use){
return new ModelAndView("register");

}
@RequestMapping("/insert")
public ModelAndView successMessage(@ModelAttribute user use){
if(use != null){
    userDaoImpl.insertData(use);
}
return new ModelAndView("success" ,"name", use.getuName());
}
@RequestMapping("/login")
public ModelAndView getUserList(@ModelAttribute user u){
List<user> userList = userDaoImpl.getData();
int len = userList.size();
for(int i = 0;i<= len ; i++){
    String userr = userList.get(i).getuName();
    if(userr.equals(u.getuName())){
        return new ModelAndView("quiz","name", u.getuName());
    }
}
return new ModelAndView("register");
}
@RequestMapping("/userSign")
public ModelAndView getUser(String name){

List<user> userList = userDaoImpl.getData();
int len = userList.size();
for(int i = 0;i<= len ; i++){
    String userr = userList.get(i).getuName();
    if(userr.equals(name)){
        return new ModelAndView("quiz","name", name);
    }
}
return new ModelAndView("error","name",name);
}
}
```

Comment: Where is `play.jsp` located in current webapp?

Comment: In WEB-INF/jsp
every jsp files are located in this folder except index.jsp

Comment: what url its shows in address bar after you click?

Comment: Try placing `play.jsp` in same dir as `index.jsp`.

Comment: thank you @SagarRohankar it worked but won't there be any security issue  I mean what I have understand till now is the file inside WEB-INF folder are not easily accessible and the files outside it are easily accessible.

Comment: it shows play.jsp @ShashwatKumar

Comment: try using href="<c:url value='play.jsp' />"

Comment: @ShashwatKumar it didn't work it gives error

Comment: what error its giving?